# How to put weight to views added dynamically on an Android layout?

Tags: java, android, layout

I have the following Layout:

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/cat_card_list_item_card"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
android:minHeight="118dp" >

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/effectContainer"
            android:orientation="vertical"/>


</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

[image]

which gets added dynamically with the objects as you see below:

Tremolo + button is one object, and the rest is 2 objects that have each one a vertical seekbar. I want the first object to have height `wrap_content`, which seems it does,a nd the rest to expand vertically as max as possible, so the seekbars grow. I've made their height "wrap_content":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/paramWrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/paramLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Subtitle1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/curLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Subtitle2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/minLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Caption" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:rotation="270" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/maxLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Caption" />

</LinearLayout>
```

but they still wont grow. How do I make them take the entire space they can?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve it out with this custom library... Just add this to your build.gradle

```
implementation 'com.h6ah4i.android.widget.verticalseekbar:verticalseekbar:1.0.0'
```

And your XML should be like this:

```
<com.h6ah4i.android.widget.verticalseekbar.VerticalSeekBarWrapper
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="10">
        <com.h6ah4i.android.widget.verticalseekbar.VerticalSeekBar
            android:id="@+id/mySeekBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:max="100"
            android:progress="0"
            android:splitTrack="false"
            app:seekBarRotation="CW90" /> <!-- Rotation: CW90 or CW270 -->
    </com.h6ah4i.android.widget.verticalseekbar.VerticalSeekBarWrapper>
```

I have tested this, and it will give you exactly what you want

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

for the SeekBar?

Comment: with this, they span from top to bottom of their parent widget, which is the group of "title number number seekbar number". And they get on top of it. Not what I needed: for the entire group to expand.

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs, may I ask you to try just for layout_width="match_parent", for the height leave "wrap_content"

Comment: I get the same thing

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs Interesting... When I tested your code I got the same thing as you on that screenshot above but if I hardcode the layout_width the SeekBar will extend... The different values of the layout_width will give the different lengths of the SeekBar. Seems like this line of code makes the problem android:rotation="270" if the layout_width is "wrap_content" then the SeekBar doesn't have enough space to grow.